# Expiring Digital Certificates for UPS Developer Kit

Tags: magento2, ups

Got this message from UPS today.. will this affect Magento 2 site? Any action we will need to take?

---

### URGENT: Expiring Digital Certificates for
UPS® Developer Kit URL

The current Comodo Sectigo server certificate used for UPS Developer Kit transactions submitted to https://onlinetools.ups.com will expire on February 25, 2021.
Beginning February 15, 2021, UPS will update the certificate to the current Comodo Sectigo at which time customers can download the new certificate. The migration will be completed February 19, 2021.

Most customer interfaces will download the certificate automatically. In the event your application uses a separate certificate store you will need to work with your IT resources to update it.

After February 19, 2021 if your certificate has not been updated your UPS Developer Kit API transactions will fail.

If you have any technical questions or concerns, please submit your question to uoltects@ups.com. For general questions, please call 1-800-247-9035.

Comment: Did you get any solution or suggestion outside of stackexchange on this issue?

Comment: @CharulTyagi Not yet. But we can softly ignore this warning.

Comment: Yes, We discussed with UPS support team, they said that they are updating their certificate no action needs from Site Owner side ignore the notification.